# How to filter gmail notifications in iOS/watchOS without smart features/personalisation?

Tags: ios, notifications, gmail, apple-watch

I'd like to find a way to only be notified on my iPhone & watch when a specific list of people contact me on gmail.  Is there any way to do this *without* enabling "smart features & personalisation" in GMail. Maybe some kind of shortcuts feature, or something else?